# Asp.net webforms generated code not well formatted

Tags: asp.net

Hi I recently started to learn asp.net webforms and I noticed that the code it generates is very messy when you check the source code of the page.Here is what I mean:
[image]

Is there a way to make the code look better formated or is this the way that webforms should generate code?

Comment: It doesn't look very messy to me, as I always used it this way. How would you like to see it instead?

Comment: well ussually when I wright my own HTML for example what is inside div.center should be one tab further then the begining of the tag this rule should aply to all parent child tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do anything to repair it.

Comment: You can manually update it, but at some point VS will mess it up again most likely. Have you tried Control K + Control D?